# which forecasting model is used in forecast() in forecast package in R?

Tags: r, forecasting

I used forecast() from forecast package in R to forecast marks of a school student. I assumed a time series of marks with frequency of 4 i.e. quarterly for 4 years. The results were fairly good. Now I want to know which forecasting model is being used in the function as I have little knowledge of statistics and it is difficult for me to identify a suitable model for predicting a student's marks.
Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the help files. Here is an excerpt from `help(forecast)`:

> The function `forecast.ts` makes forecasts using `ets` models (if the data
>   are non-seasonal or the seasonal period is 12 or less) or `stlf` (if the
>   seasonal period is 13 or more).